# Вывод текстового поля с помощью pdoPage в Modx

Tags: php, modx

Есть каталог с товарами. У каждого товара есть дополнительное текстовое поле (`tv`), которое должно выводится в каталоге.

Вывод в каталоге выглядит так:

```
<li>[[!pdoPage?
    &parents=`[[*id]]`
    &ajaxMode=`default`
    &limit=`16`
    &element=`msProducts`
    &tpl=`tpl.productsListItem`
    ]]</li>
```

Соответственно в `tpl.productsListItem`:

```
<div class="list_products_img">
   <a href="[[~[[+id]]]]"><img src="[[!phpthumbon? &input=`[[+image]]` &options=`w=200&h=203&zc=1`]]" alt=""></a>
</div>
<div class="list_products_name">
   [[+product]]
</div>
```

Поле выводит, но вместо текстового значения поля `product` отображается `0`. Как стоит поправить?

Answer (score 1):

добавить `` &includeTVs=`product` ``